# Отправка писем с помощью SMTP. Python

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

Как реализовать рассылку писем с помощью smtplib без использования логина и пароля отправляющей стороны server.login(username, password)?

Comment: Очевидно, настроить сервер так, чтобы он позволял отправку без логина и пароля

Comment: Если напишите, через какой smtp сервер будет отправка (postfix, exim, sendmail, etc), то возможно вам скажут как его настроить.

Comment: Это не зависит от вашего python-кода, это зависит от настроек smtp-сервера, который вы будете юзать для отправки.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что лучше использовать сервисы рассылок. Есть и беспалтные, например  [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) дает возможность отправить 10К писем на каждый месяц совершенно беспалтно. Нужно настроит на стороне админки Mailgun-а, а также на сервере. 
А так туда просто нужно отрпавлять POST запросы. вобщем прочитайте доки.

надеюсь, что поможет